# React Router Link not refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes, react-router

Good Morning, I Have a header component witha navbar and some Links from react router inside it, the header is called in my app component and the links have some display conditions relative to authentication. The problem is when I click on any link on the header the page changes but the header himself stays the same for example login, logout when I click on login login component should be hidden and logout component displayed but it doesn't work. Ps : When I change  with   Everything works fine

```
function TodoApp() {
//   let isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn();
//   console.log(isUserLoggedIn);
  //   render() {
  return (
    <div className="TodoApp">
     { <Router>
        <div>
          <HeaderComponent isUserLoggedIn={AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={withRouter(LoginComponent)} />
            <Route path="/login" component={withRouter(LoginComponent)} />
            <AuthenticatedRoute
              path="/welcome/:name"
              component={withRouter(WelcomeComponent)}
            />
            <AuthenticatedRoute
              path="/todos"
              component={withRouter(ListTodosComponent)}
            />
            <AuthenticatedRoute
              path="/logout"
              component={withRouter(LogoutComponent)}
            />
            <Route component={withRouter(ErrorComponent)} />
          </Switch>
          <FooterComponent />
        </div>
     </Router>
      {/* <LoginComponent /> */}
    </div>
  );
  }
}

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  //   this.state = {
  //     isUserLoggedIn: AuthenticationSevice.isUserLoggedIn(),
  //   };
  //   //  this.handleState = this.handleState.bind(this);
  // }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Header charged");
  }

  //   handleState = () => {
  //     this.setState(() => {
  //         return { isUserLoggedIn: AuthenticationSevice.isUserLoggedIn() };
  //       });
  //       console.log(this.state.isUserLoggedIn);
  //   }

  render() {
    // const isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationSevice.isUserLoggedIn();
    return (
      <header>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <div>
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="https://github.com/sbouhaddi">
              Sbouhaddi
            </a>
          </div>
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            {this.props.isUserLoggedIn && (
              <li>
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/welcome/Sbouhaddi">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
            {this.props.isUserLoggedIn && (
              <li>
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/todos">
                  Todos
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>
          <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
            {!this.props.isUserLoggedIn && (
              <li>
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/login">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
            {this.props.isUserLoggedIn && (
              <li>
                <Link
                  className="nav-link"
                  onClick={AuthenticationSevice.logout}
                  to="/logout"
                >
                  Logout
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear you call your `AuthenticationService` logged-in function to pass a value to the `isUserLoggedIn` prop.

`AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn` vs `AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()`

```
<HeaderComponent isUserLoggedIn={AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()} />
```